# How to bind a datasource to a label control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

It's easy to bind a data source to something like a gridview or repeater, but how would I do it with a label? Heres the sql connection that I want to modify. By the way, I don't need 2 way binding.

```
public void Sql_Connection(string queryString)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

The query I'm using:

SELECT Description FROM RbSpecials WHERE Active=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public string SqlConnection(string queryString)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = queryString;
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // This will return the first result 
                // but there might be other
                return reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will also ensure that in case of exception all disposable objects are disposed and will properly return the `SQLConnection` to the connection pool in order to be reused.

And finally assign the `Text` property of the label:

```
lblTest.Text = SqlConnection("SELECT Description FROM RbSpecials WHERE Active=1");
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ExecuteReader` rather than `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
public void Sql_Connection(string queryString)
{
     using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings"RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
     {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
        {
           conn.Open();
           using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while(rdr.Read())
               {
                   lblDescription.Text = rdr.GetString(0); 
               }
           }
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   SqlDataReader adpt = cmd.ExecureReader();
   if(rdr.Read())
    {
      lblName.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
    }
 }
```